# Getting a duplicate of pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have these list items:

```
<li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Home", "Index", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "updaterDiv" })</li>
<li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Recs", "Recs", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "updaterDiv" }) </li>
<li>@Ajax.ActionLink("Software", "Software", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "updaterDiv" }) </li>
...
```

And the updaterDiv for the Ajax actionlinks looks like this:

```
<div id="updaterDiv" style="height: 500px; width: 700px; margin-top: 50px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
    @RenderBody()
</div>
```

I want the Index partial page to be the first page that is shown when the site is loaded.
Right now I have this in the Index action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Home";
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return PartialView("_Index");
    }
    return View(); //also tried return PartialView("_Index");
}
```

The index page will load fine, but when I click on the tab that calls the Index action, I get a duplicate of the page, and weird stuff happens. My tabs MUST be Ajax actionlinks. It's easy to do so that the index is loaded on page start, but once I click on the "Home tab", that calls the index Action, all hell breaks lose. How can I avoid this?
I also tried this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Home";
    return PartialView("_Index");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its seems that @RenderBody() is creating an issue here and creating duplicate html. You need to put @RenderBody() outside from the ajax div.

Or just try the folloeing jquery code

```
$(function(){

$('#btnIndexId').click(function(){
$('#updaterDiv').load('/home/index');
});

});
```

Comment: At first I also thought that it was the Renderbody(). At the begining it was outside the updaterDiv, but it makes no difference whether it's inside or outside the updaterDiv

Comment: Are you trying this ajax code on layout.cshtml page?

Comment: Yes the tabs that use the Ajax code are in _Layout.cshtml

Comment: you can also try with jquery load div with ajax, I have updated my answer please review.